# Php exec - not work with parameters

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I need to use `exec()` function, but it doesn't work with params.

It works:

`exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe');`

It doesn't:

`exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot=D:\file211.png --window-size=1920,1200 http://google.com')`

What to do to set params in exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php:

> Note: On Windows exec() will first start cmd.exe to launch the
>   command. If you want to start an external program without starting
>   cmd.exe use proc_open() with the bypass_shell option set.

You can also use popen() instead of proc_open():

`$handle = popen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot=D:\file211.png --window-size=1920,1200 http://google.com', 'r');`

...